# on PV systems not connected to Net-metering or batteries, if there is no demand where does the power go?

Tags: solar-cell

on PV system that is connected to the grid, but has no net metering and no batteries, where does the power go when there isn't demand?

Comment: Please be professional, punctuate and use correct grammar. Questions should be specific and not open ended and preferably related to design. That being said an unconnected solar cell will simply generate heat within itself. PV systems have various means for dealing with this problem.

Comment: PV systems will usually operate with no load without problem. If a load is not provided for potentially available energy, the energy is not produced. A panel or panels will produce voltage and will provide current about proportional to insolation level IF there is a current path available. As power = V x I, if no I is drawn then no power is produced.

Answer (score 1):

If the system is connected to the grid, the extra power goes to the grid even if you don't have a net metering device. Because the decision of sending the extra power comes from the inverter not from the net metering.

But I don't think there is a jurisdiction that allows to connect a PV system to the grid without a net metering device.

Comment: I have in the UK a PV system which is grid-connected, has a generation meter, but does *not* do true net metering - the house input meter never runs backwards. Perfectly fine here.

Comment: Thank you for the information, but I think it's not good financially to have a PV system without a backwards metering. What is the benefit to have like this system?

Comment: The bureaucracy is easier, and you get paid for a 'deemed export' quantity: http://www.goodenergy.co.uk/blog/2011/10/05/exporting-your-home-generated-electricity-deemed-vs-metered , *in addition* to being paid for every unit that comes off the panels exported or not.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a bare solar panel that doesn't have a load connected to it, the power doesn't go anywhere.

The free electrons and holes created by the light recombine right there in the solar cells if there's no external path for them to flow through.

With a grid-tied system, the power goes into the grid, regardless of how it's metered. I don't know what you mean by "no net metering" and "there isn't demand".